# How do I set a global error handler without overriding existing RabbitListenerContainerFactory in Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a situation where there are many downstream projects using a same common library holding the RabbitMQ configuration.

I want to add a global error handler in such common configuration but pretty much all online documentation says that I have to declare my own `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` so that I can set my error handler in the bean definition code (e.g. via autowiring a `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` whose by the way I haven't fully understood the purpose).

However, I don't want to override any existing `RabbitListenerContainerFactory`, because some of the downstream projects declare their own implementation of it, and I don't want to go and set my global error handler for each of them. I want to declare the global error handler only in the common library and once for all.

How can I do that by using the existing implementation of `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` whatever that is?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I have found a working solution.

```java
@Configuration
public class SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryExtraConfig {

  public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryExtraConfig(
      final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory,
      final MyErrorHandler handler) {
    factory.setErrorHandler(handler);
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to configure a different one for each container, add a `ContainerCustomizer` to the factory.

Comment: Would be nice, if you only have to expose an error handler bean and Spring Boot/AMQP would pick it up automatically.